# Angular.js jQuery error when using ng-include

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using Angular's `ng-include` in my SPA project and, though things appear to be working fine, I'm getting the following error:

```
angular.js:12116 SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js:2:2622
at Function.m.extend.globalEval (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js:2:2633)
at m.fn.extend.domManip (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js:3:23107)
at m.fn.extend.append (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js:3:20620)
at .<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js:3:22151)
at m.access (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js:3:3399)
at m.fn.extend.html (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js:3:21736)
at link (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/Angular/angular.min.js:251:377)
at aa (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/Angular/angular.min.js:71:279)
at Z (http://127.0.0.1:49463/Public_Libs/Angular/angular.min.js:60:329) <div class="panel-body slide-animate-container ng-scope" ng-include="Get_Current_Sub_Page_in_Main_Panel()">
```

I don't quite see what the error could be.

Comment: it looks like a syntax error. Check your code again.

Comment: agree with Abdul ... SyntaxError: missing )

Comment: post your code, something wrong with your syntax

Comment: syntax error check code or place code in here

Comment: I think I found it... All my code is within **controllers** except for a piece that I took from Facebook to include a Log-In button. If the error was  within a controller, the error would make it `not a function`. I just removed the Facebook part and the error disappeared. will check it further but at least I know where to look for it. Thank you guys!!!!!

Comment: This question still needs an [mcve] - although it may be OK to just let it close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in a piece of code I copied-pasted from Facebook (interesting...). Indeed, a "**)**" was missing.

Thanks to all for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your function function in your code lose `syntax`[)].You'd better check it clearly or use JS hint.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found the error in a piece of code **delivered by Facebook** simple missing ")". See my comment above. Now it is working fine.